# How to use he/she (or another word) when we dont know what the other person is a man or woman?

Tags: word-usage

So in meetings, text, documents etc, and speaking to other people we discuss what users should do or will do.

So for example,  a sentence could be 'the user enter his/her username and then he/she needs to click on the button to continue'

Each time do we need to use he/she , or there is another way to write the same ?

Comment: Use the singular *they* or *the user*, etc

Comment: using 'the user' again and again sounds wrong , maybe its grammatically correct but its just sounds like you are repeating yourself.

Comment: @DanielBenedykt “*The user* wants to foo the bar, so *they* frob the baz and then frick the blum”. An alternative is to create user personas and name and gender them. “Alice is a power user, she wants more control and flexibility, whereas Bob is a casual user and wants simplicity and convenience. So we need to allow users to change their settings, like Alice will, but implement intelligent defaults for Bob”. You get the idea.